# C++11 unordered_map time complexity

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, time-complexity, unordered-map

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do a cache for resources. I am mainly looking for native C/C++/C++11 solutions (i.e. I don't have boost and the likes as an option).

What I am doing when retrieving from the cache is something like this:

```
Object *ResourceManager::object_named(const char *name) {
    if (_object_cache.find(name) == _object_cache.end()) {
        _object_cache[name] = new Object();
    }
    return _object_cache[name];
}
```

Where `_object_cache` is defined something like: `std::unordered_map <std::string, Object *> _object_cache;`

What I am wondering is about the time complexity of doing this, does find trigger a linear-time search or is it done as some kind of a look-up operation?

I mean if I do `_object_cache["something"];` on the given example it will either return the object or if it doesn't exist it will call the default constructor inserting an object which is not what I want. I find this a bit counter-intuitive, I would have expected it to report in some way (returning `nullptr` for example) that a `value` for the `key` couldn't be retrieved, not second-guess what I wanted.

But again, if I do a `find` on the key, does it trigger a big search which in fact will run in linear time (since the key will not be found it will look at every key)?

Is this a good way to do it, or does anyone have some suggestions, perhaps it's possible to use a look up or something to know if the key is available or not, I may access often and if it is the case that some time is spent searching I would like to eliminate it or at least do it as fast as possible.

Thankful for any input on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default constructor (triggered by `_object_cache["something"]`) is what you want; the default constructor for a pointer type (e.g. `Object *`) gives `nullptr` (8.5p6b1, footnote 103).

So:

```
auto &ptr = _object_cache[name];
if (!ptr) ptr = new Object;
return ptr;
```

You use a reference into the unordered map (`auto &ptr`) as your local variable so that you assign into the map and set your return value in the same operation.  In C++03 or if you want to be explicit, write `Object *&ptr` (a reference to a pointer).

Note that you should probably be using `unique_ptr` rather than a raw pointer to ensure that your cache manages ownership.

By the way, `find` has the same performance as `operator[]`; average constant, worst-case linear (only if every key in the unordered map has the same hash).

Comment: Thanks for the answer (actually to all answers I've received), I especially liked the concise explanations. I feel that I better understand both the answer to my question, and I also like the note about using `unique_ptr` which makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd write this:

```
auto it = _object_cache.find(name);
return it != _object_cache.end()
       ? it->second
       : _object_cache.emplace(name, new Object).first->second;
```

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of `find` on an std::unordered_map is O(1) (constant), specially with std::string keys which have good hashing leading to very low rate of collisions. Even though the name of the method is `find`, it doesn't do a linear scan as you pointed out.

If you want to do some kind of caching, this container is definitely a good start.

Comment: What does "specially" mean? "It's constant, but with strings it's even more constant"?

Comment: @KerrekSB did you read the entire answer? I will repeat that for you: "specially with std::string keys which have good hashing leading to very low rate of collisions". I was trying to say that std::string has a good built-in hashing thru std::hash<>, whereas when you have your own object as key you must implement the hashing yourself, which might not be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a `cache` typically is not just a fast `O(1)` access but also a **bounded** data structure. The `std::unordered_map` will dynamically increase its size when more and more elements are added. When resources are limited (e.g. reading huge files from disk into memory), you want a bounded and fast data structure to improve the responsiveness of your system.

In contrast, a `cache` will use an **eviction** strategy whenever `size()` reaches `capacity()`, by replacing the least valuable element.

You can implement a `cache` on top of a `std::unordered_map`. The eviction strategy can then be implemented by redefining the `insert()` member. If you want to go for an `N`-way (for small and fixed `N`) associative cache (i.e. one item can replace at most `N` other items), you could use the `bucket()` interface to replace one of the bucket's entries.

For a fully associative cache (i.e. any item can replace any other item), you could use a Least Recently Used eviction strategy by adding a `std::list` as a secondary data structure:

```
using key_tracker_type = std::list<K>; 
using key_to_value_type = std::unordered_map< 
    K,std::pair<V,typename key_tracker_type::iterator> 
>;
```

By wrapping these two structures inside your `cache` class, you can define the `insert()` to trigger a replace when your capacity is full. When that happens, you `pop_front()` the Least Recently Used item and `push_back()` the current item into the list.

On [**Tim Day's blog there is an extensive example**](http://timday.bitbucket.org/lru.html) with full source code that implements the above cache data structure. It's implementation can also be done efficiently using Boost.Bimap or Boost.MultiIndex.

Answer (score 0):

The insert/emplace interfaces to map/unordered_map are enough to do what you want: find the position, and insert if necessary. Since the mapped values here are pointers, ekatmur's response is ideal. If your values are fully-fledged objects in the map rather than pointers, you could use something like this:

```
Object& ResourceManager::object_named(const char *name, const Object& initialValue) {
    return _object_cache.emplace(name, initialValue).first->second;
}
```

The values `name` and `initialValue` make up arguments to the key-value pair that needs to be inserted, if there is no key with the same value as `name`. The `emplace` returns a pair, with `second` indicating whether anything was inserted (the key in `name` is a new one) - we don't care about that here; and `first` being the iterator pointing to the (perhaps newly created) key-value pair entry with key equivalent to the value of `name`. So if the key was already there, dereferencing `first` gives the original `Ojbect` for the key, which has not been overwritten with `initialValue`; otherwise, the key was newly inserted using the value of `name` and the entry's value portion copied from `initialValue`, and `first` points to that.

ekatmur's response is equivalent to this:

```
Object& ResourceManager::object_named(const char *name) {
    bool res;
    auto iter = _object_cache.end();
    std::tie(iter, res) = _object_cache.emplace(name, nullptr);
    if (res) {
        iter->second = new Object(); // we inserted a null pointer - now replace it
    }
    return iter->second;
}
```

but profits from the fact that the default-constructed pointer value created by `operator[]` is null to decide whether a new `Object` needs to be allocated. It's more succinct and easier to read.